# Android reading from files and occasionally incorrect values

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, file-io

**DISCLAIMER**

The problem has been fixed, as I described in the comments. I was thinking of deleting it since there was no answer and I didn't want to confuse others, but my fix doesn't necessarily target the problem but works around it. So, I'll just keep it in the hopes that one day someone will find an answer.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am using the android ndk to read from some files and I am having a few issues with the output. The thing is, it is working most of the time, but it occasionally gives wrong input. Below is how my code is set up (note that this isn't the complete code, but if more information is needed I'll add it. I just want to keep it simple). The exact problem is the code below.

1. In the NDK C++ file, I am using fstream to read from the files. The files are stored in the phone's internal memory, so it's working fine. There's 2 files:

1.1 : file1.cpp

```
JNIExport jdoubleArray class_path_nativeMethod 
                (JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz, jint index, jint size){
    jdouble dubArray[6];
    jdoubleArray result;
    result = env->NewDoubleArray(size);

    string s = "/sdcard/" + construct_fileName(index);

    ifstream is;
    if(is.fail()){
       return NULL; 
    }
    is.open(s.c_str());

    // read something from the files 
    // save it into dubArray
    // assign dubArray to result

    return result;
}
```

1.2 : file2.cpp

```
string construct_fileName(int index){
    string s;

    switch(index){
    case 0:
        s = "file1.ext";
        break;
    case 1:
        s = "file2.ext";
        break;
    case 2:
        s = "file3.ext";
        break;
    default:
        // something
    }

    return s;
}
```

2 Now my main activity, MainActivity.java

```
private TextView output;
private TextView output2;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private Button calculateButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    this.output2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    this.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    this.calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

public void calculate(View v){
    int index;
    switch (v.getId()){
    case(R.id.button1){
        switch(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
        case R.id.radio0:
            index = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.radio1:
            index = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.radio2:
            index = 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    double arr[] = CppMethods.nativeCalculations(index, 2);
    Double i, j;
    i = Double.valueOf(arr[0]);
    j = Double.valueOf(arr[1]);
    this.output.setText(i.toString().subSequence(0, i.toString().length()));
    this.output2.setText(j.toString().subSequence(0, j.toString().length()));
    }
}
```

So the problem is, the value in the textviews is correct for most of the time. But, let's say I have the `radio0` button selected, and I press the `button` object 50 times, I will get incorrect output in the text views 5 or 6 times, and correct output in the other times.

Some information that could be useful:

- When the output is incorrect, I get some outrageous number, like 2.72364283467E17, whereas the outputs I am expecting are double values less than 20, as stored in the files.
- When the output is incorrect, both textviews have the ridiculous number shown above
- The code is correct for sure, because the output is correct most of the time.

Sorry for the long question,

Thanks,

NAX

Comment: may I ask why you are doing this, this way?

Comment: This is temporary. The reason why I am inputting the files with c++ is that I will process them there before returning the value. Like I said, most of the stuff above is only temporary, but I need it to work in order to move on.

Comment: hmm... well without knowing whether or not this is your actual code, all I can tell you is that you forgot a ';' after your first break

Comment: That's not the problem, but I fixed it for you

Comment: have you tried doing this all in java? At the very least try all your file operations with java, if even for a simple test.

Comment: I would, but I mean, I don't understand why the output is correct most of the time: the file names don't change, and the only options for user input are those 3 radio buttons. Let's say it works in java, that wouldn't help me, because my c++ code is not incorrect. I would ask: are there known issues with reading files using the ndk? Or returning arrays through from the jni native code to java?

Comment: that's understandable,  but again why are you trying to use both?   what's the benefit?

Comment: This is a program that I already have on desktop. I am trying to make a mobile equivalent, that processes the data; runs an optimization that actually takes a few minutes, and speed is important. The only reason I am returning the arrays to my java code is just to check if the values are properly imported

Comment: ... And I'm doing this by outputting the values onto the text views, hence the ugly code you see above

Comment: Can you clarify what code is executed when you click on your button for your testing. Is the testing done on device on in emulator. Does very button click mean that every time you are opening a file (from SD card), reading it and then closing it?

Comment: Ok. First of all, I made a mistake in inputting the first code, but I fixed it now. If you look at the code for the main activity, the button I press is the `Button` object `button1`, you can see it from the java code. When you press it, we check which radio button is selected, and based on that, selects a value for the index, which is then passed on to the native function. Based on that value, the folder-name I am targetting in the SD card is chosen, and I read the files accordingly. Is that clear?

Comment: Ok guys, I just did something that takes care of my problem for now. I still don't understand what is causing the problem, but I don't need to. Basically, I created a check integer which is initialized at 1000 and then I attempt to read values from the file into it that integer. If the value is still 1000 (too high for my files), then I will simply try to read again, until I get a successful read. It's fine now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: do you think I should delete this question? I don't want to confuse people, and the problem could be somewhere else in the code, but I don't think anything else is relevant. At the same time, it's a big program.

Comment: wow, ok, sorry for that, possibly drunk, but mainly SO mobile's fault... The only reason I can think that might be the problem is clicking the button too quickly. If no one can answer this question, no don't delete it, but post a new question regarding whether there are known issues passing variables/arrays from native code...

Answer (score 0):

It may not solve your problem, but the following points I noticed may help you:

1. In your `file1.cpp`, error handling for `env->NewDoubleArray()` is missed (or did you miss it intentionally for posting?)
2. I don't know how you assign the `double`s to the `jdoubleArray`, but here are some best practice suggestions from **Google** (in fact it's applicable for other JNI environments too):

   - [JNI Tips - Primitive Arrays](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#arrays)
   - [JNI Tips - Region Calls](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#region_calls)
3. Threading issues 1: If your native code is not prepared for multi-threading, I think it's better to add `synchronized` to `CppMethods.nativeCalculations()` (since the `fstream` may still be opening when another call comes if not doing so):

   ```
   public class CppMethods {
       public static native synchronized double[] nativeCalculations(int index, int size);
   }
   ```
4. Threading issues 2: You may need something like [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to wrap the [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) calls. Besides, I wonder why you made your call to [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) so complicated, I think this is enough (by the way, a [`String`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) is a [`CharSequence`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)):

   ```
   final double[] arr = CppMethods.nativeCalculations(index, 2);
   this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           this.output.setText(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
           this.output2.setText(String.valueOf(arr[1]));
       }
   });
   ```